# Remove huge blockchain file from windows 10 backup

Tags: windows-10, backup

I have used a cryptocurrency program wallet (Ethereum) in windows 10, which seems to download the complete the blockchain (wich  80GB++).  I already exclude the spot from my windows 10 backup, but my external hard drive is full. I don't want to mess with all my other files and want to go back in time when needed.

I wonder how I can remove this huge blockchain file(s) from my backup

Comment: Delete the backup and then create a new backup.  The built-in backup tool doesn't have any way to remove this file from the backups

Comment: If you are doing an incremental backup, do one full backup with the folder excluded.